# A suitable MVC / MOSS 2010 Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

We currently are running moss 2007 for an enterprise internet facing site. The site's main functionality is surfaced using FAST search with MOSS 2007 used for the cms aspects. We find that the performance and development experience inside of MOSS to have been quite painful.

We are planning to migrate to MOSS 2010 but the plan is to use this as a data store only and to seperate the architecture into an MVC web application front end, with MOSS being used as a repository for the data. MOSS administration will continue to be the same but our front end rendering/logic will be a lightweight aspnet mvc site.

Would really appreciate others views on this as an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *As answered on [SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/moss-and-mvc-architecture-question)*

This can of course be done, but with some changes to Sharepoint app. You can [check this out](http://vspug.com/mbailey/files/2010/04/Using-ASP.NET-MVC-2-with-Sharepoint-Publishing.pdf) that does exactly what you're intending to do and may help you lots while doing it because it has a step by step tutorial how to achieve it.

End product ([www.TheMedicineCabinet.co.uk](http://www.TheMedicineCabinet.co.uk)) is an Asp.net MVC application running inside Sharepoint context and using Sharepoint as the backing store.